# CronJob on MacOSX seems to be delayed. Is it normal?

Tags: macos, cron

I am running a cronjob on MacOSX. It just prints some information on a file every 5 minutes.

I added a `date` command, and I see that the job runs sometimes after 10-15 seconds, but other times it can run after 1-2 minutes.

I also added a `time` command to check if the problem was the command itself that I run (i.e. the information I print), but it takes only some milliseconds, as expected. So the problem seems not to be the command I execute.

Is this delay of several minutes (up to 2 minutes) normal?

Comment: Do you have other cron/at jobs executed on this system?

Comment: I found no other cronjob manually set in my user, or in the admin user. There could be some scheduled process running, it is a build server running GoCD, but it is not used for anything else, AFAIK

Comment: To give you some more information, we see problems while building, it seems that often it can not contact Apple to sign the artifact, or update the artifact to the Go server. If I ping a website continously, sometimes many packets are just lost. I could not understand why. So, I was printing every 5 minutes some Network information to investigate the problem (everything seems fine on the Network, the output is as expected), and I noticed this delay in the cronjob. Maybe it can lead to another problem?

Comment: The case with `cron` is this software do not offer exact time execution. Also it exec the tasks consecutive, and this is the reason I ask about other jobs. Usually delay can be caused by heavy load on the machine. But IMHO 2 minutes is too much...